In bash, how would I start another command before the first is finished?
I'm trying to run a command on roughly 10,000 files. The command does not require any information from other files, and each command deposits the output in a separate txt file. Currently, I am using a loop, but am trying to find out if there is a way to run the commands in parallel.
I can increase the amount of nodes I'm using, the amount of tasks per node, the cpus per task, the allocated memory, and the time allowed for the loop to complete.
What would be the best way to run the command in parallel as much as the system can handle?
Here is my loop:
for file in *.ctl; do
        /N/project/tomWGS/OVULERNASEQ/scripts/moEvoScripts/Programs/paml/bin/codeml "${file}"
done

Thank you for your time,
-tbiewerh

for f in *; do cmd $f; done will run cmd serially.  for f in *; do cmd $f& done will run in parallel.  That is, just replace ; with &

IOW, just append & at the end of the line in which you execute the command.  There is no real difference between a ; and a newline in this case, so you can either replace the newline with & or just insert a & before the newline.

One should just wait the program at the end so to be safe, and actually probably before to be more safe. Running 10_000 process is certainly not a good idea. At best, it will crash because of too many processes created. In the worst case, it is gonna look like a fork bomb slowing down the whole system. It may saturate your resources like your RAM and the OOM killer may kill critical process (not even the one you started in this script).

Often doing it in a for loop works fine, even with 10,000 items, if you simply put a tiny sleep in-between the steps, like this: for File in *; do command "$File" & sleep 0.01s; done.  Most modern computers can handle 10,000 jobs alright (depending on RAM usage), but if you try to launch them all simultaneously it tends to choke and lag like crazy.

"as much as the system can handle" is the difficult part, here. This depends on the available resources and their consumption by your jobs. Assuming you can yourself identify a maximum number of concurrent jobs, say 12, there are several options:
find and GNU xargs
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.ctl' -print0 |
xargs -0 -n1 -P12 /N/project/tomWGS/OVULERNASEQ/scripts/moEvoScripts/Programs/paml/bin/codeml

find lists all ctl files separated by a NUL character (-print0) and this is piped to GNU xargs that also considers the inputs as NUL-separated (-0), consumes one input argument per job (-n1) and runs up to 12 jobs in parallel (-P12).
Using NUL as a separator allows your file names to have arbitrary names, including with newline characters.
find and GNU parallel
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.ctl' -print0 |
parallel -0 -n1 -P12 /N/project/tomWGS/OVULERNASEQ/scripts/moEvoScripts/Programs/paml/bin/codeml

That's exactly the same as with xargs. Note that GNU parallel can determine the optimal number of jobs during a warm-up period. But the efficiency strongly depends on the use cases. Try -P0 instead of -P12 and see if it works better than with a fixed number. Note also that GNU parallel can run jobs on several computers. See the manual for the details.
GNU make
Use this only if your file names do not contain spaces. Create a file named Makefile in your source directory (the one containing the ctl files) and containing (replace the leading spaces before $(CODEML) $< with a tab):
# Makefile
CODEML := /N/project/tomWGS/OVULERNASEQ/scripts/moEvoScripts/Programs/paml/bin/codeml
CTLS   := $(wildcard *.ctl)
JOBS   := $(patsubst %,%-job,$(CTLS))

.PHONY: all $(JOBS)
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
all: $(JOBS)
$(JOBS): %-job: %
    $(CODEML) $<

Type make -j12. make will run up to 12 jobs in parallel until all jobs complete. Using GNU make may look uselessly complicated, compared to the other solutions, but there is an interesting benefit: you can ask make to run codeml only if the ctl file changed since the last time. make does this by comparing the last modification time of a result file and a source file.
Assume codeml foo.ctl produces file foo.mlb and you modify the Makefile as follows (replace the leading spaces before $(CODEML) $< with a tab):
# Makefile
CODEML := /N/project/tomWGS/OVULERNASEQ/scripts/moEvoScripts/Programs/paml/bin/codeml
CTLS   := $(wildcard *.ctl)
MLBS   := $(patsubst %.ctl,%.mlb,$(CTLS))

.PHONY: all
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
all: $(MLBS)
%.mlb: %.ctl
    $(CODEML) $<

Then, if you type make -j12, make will run a maximum of 12 jobs simultaneously, but it will only run the jobs for which the mlb file is older than the ctl file. This way, if you modify only 100 of your ctl files and run make -j12 again, it should take far less than the first time because only 100 jobs will be launched, instead of 10000.

If someone wants to use this method, you can find the ideal number of processes by monitoring top to watch the load average change.  Ideally it will settle slightly above 1.00, which means that for every process finishing, one is waiting to go.  Peak efficiency.  I forget if the load average is per-core or in-total, i.e. if a peak loaded 4-core system has a load average of 1.00 or 4.00.  You can also look at the idle/unused CPU time, which you want to get down to zero percent.  Plus you can monitor free RAM in top as well, to ensure you don't completely run out of memory.

The find and GNU parallel was an effective and efficient solution, cutting Job time to a tenth of the time it had taken previously. I did it with the P0 instead of the P12. Thank you for the help.

You can place a script invocation in the background by appending & on the end of the call (eg, codeml "${file}" &) but you need to be careful about the number of these you place in the background at the same time.  As mentioned in the comments you run the risk of bogging down resources (cpu and/or disk throughput), using up memory ('out of memory' errors) or just plain causing your system to slow down or effectively stop due to too many active processes.
There are several ways you can manage the number of background processes including custom bash scripting (eg, loop that keeps count of number of concurrent background jobs), spawning N number of subshells in advance and then letting them chew through the list of files, or using a tool like parallel or xargs. A web search on any of these topics should generate quite a few hits with useful details and examples.
One simple approach using xargs to limit the number of background jobs ...
Setup:
$ touch test_{01..10}.ctl

$ ls *ctl
test_01.ctl  test_03.ctl  test_05.ctl  test_07.ctl  test_09.ctl
test_02.ctl  test_04.ctl  test_06.ctl  test_08.ctl  test_10.ctl

$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash

echo "$@ : $(date)"
sleep 2

Approach:

use find to generate a list of files; limit search to the current directory (-maxdepth 1); delimit filenames with a null character (-print0; insures proper processing of filenames that contain white space and/or control characters)
pipe the list of files (generated by find) to xargs
configure xargs to only run script if there is an input (-r), use null character as filename delimiter (-0), limit number of parallel threads to N (-P N), and feed X number of filenames to each script invocation (-n X)

Running 3 copies of myscript in parallel (-P 3) while insuring we feed only one filename at a time to each copy of myscript (-n 1):
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*ctl' -print0 | xargs -r -0 -P 3 -n 1 ./myscript  
./test_03.ctl : Wed Aug 28 09:24:51 CDT 2024
./test_07.ctl : Wed Aug 28 09:24:51 CDT 2024
./test_02.ctl : Wed Aug 28 09:24:51 CDT 2024
                                                -- 2 sec delay
./test_09.ctl : Wed Aug 28 09:24:53 CDT 2024
./test_08.ctl : Wed Aug 28 09:24:53 CDT 2024
./test_10.ctl : Wed Aug 28 09:24:53 CDT 2024
                                                -- 2 sec delay
./test_01.ctl : Wed Aug 28 09:24:55 CDT 2024
./test_04.ctl : Wed Aug 28 09:24:55 CDT 2024
./test_06.ctl : Wed Aug 28 09:24:55 CDT 2024
                                                -- 2 sec delay
./test_05.ctl : Wed Aug 28 09:24:57 CDT 2024



Install GNU Parallel package

Run your script in parallel as in
parallel -a ./your_shell_script


This utility will scale up the workload across available CPUs.
Please do read the parallel manual (man parallel; of course, after installing) to understand on how to use this tool better.
